Excel Formula Two Formulas in one cell
=LEFT(WELDS!A2,SEARCH("-FW",WELDS!A2)-1)

I have this formula right now, but I want to add "-IN" where the FW is so that way if the data in A2 does not have FW but IN it still works.
is there a way to do this for the same cell?
I Have tried a few things but I need help

Note that SEARCH is not case sensitive, FIND is. Not sure what's desired, but you may prefer to use FIND here?

Try using one of the following methods:


• Option One:
=TEXTBEFORE(S2,{"-FW","-IN"})


• Option Two:
=LEFT(S2,TOCOL(SEARCH({"-FW","-IN"},S2),2)-1)


• Option Three:
=LEFT(S2,SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH({"-FW","-IN"},S2),0))-1)


SEARCH() function is case-insensitive, you can also FIND() in place of SEARCH() if the search keyword is not case-sensitive, just to make the formula bit shorter with less bytes.

=LEFT(S2,TOCOL(FIND({"-FW","-IN"},S2),2)-1)



Notes: 1) TEXTBEFORE seems to apply each element of the array "delimiter" argument sequentially, provides a value; 2) SEARCH (FIND) with the array "find_text" argument returns array (!) even if the single entry is found which can affect some applications.

Case insensitive version for TEXTBEFORE: =TEXTBEFORE(S2,{"-FW","-IN"},,1)


left of the search term that is closest to the start
return original if not matched

=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,AGGREGATE(15,2,SEARCH({"-in";"-fw"},A1),1)-1),A1)



Last two rows are not "left of the first match" if I understand it correctly.

Thanks for checking @rotabor. You're right, I'll update the wording shortly. I meant the first instance of the match. So in 4) -in is the first  5) -fw is the first
